# insertion problem in drupal 6

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
  $value["name"] = $form['name']['first'];
  $contact = db_fetch_array(db_query("INSERT INTO test values('4', $value["name"])"));
```

error is shown here but what will be the correct code to submit $form data into a database?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT queries don't return a result, so there's nothing to fetch. Despite that your query is syntactically wrong: string values must be wrapped in quotes, numeric values must not.

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {test} VALUES (4, '%s')", $form['name']['first']);
```

As of Drupal 6 `db_query("INSERT ...")` is discouraged. `drupal_write_record()` should be used instead.

```
$record = array('id' => 4, 'firstname' => $form['name']['first']);
drupal_write_record('test', $record);
```

For more information please refer to the [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/group/schemaapi/6).

Comment: i have used 1st one for drupal 6 but it insert id & "textfield" into the database & 2nd one inserts nothing. What will i do now?

Comment: The value of `$form['name']['first']` is `textfield`. Use `var_dump($form['name']['first'])` to check that. Second inserts nothing because your column names are not `id` and `firstname`.

Comment: $value["name"] = $form['name']['first'];                db_query("INSERT INTO {test} VALUES (4, '%s')", var_dump($form['name']['first']));                                                         this only insert 4 but name is null here.... & i have tried for my id & name ...but inserts nothing...

Comment: db_fetch_array(db_query("INSERT INTO {category}(category_name, sort_order, date) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $form['name']['#post'], $form['name']['#post'], $date_time));     i have used this code & it works... thank you so much rik for your reply.